# Creating a relationship from Pivot Table Field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I cannot find a solution, likely to how I am phrasing the question. I have a model called `Invoice` and it has the following relationship:

```
public function manifests(){
    return $this->morphedByMany(carrier_manifest::class, 'invoiceable')->withPivot(['amount','rate_id','notes']);
}
```

As you can see, in the pivot, I have a table called `rate_id`. I would like to be able to add a relationship to another model based on the value of the `rate_id` (the model just being called `ChargeRates`). Is there a way I can do this in order to access a field in the `ChargeRates` model called `label`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to actually implement the pivot table as a model if it has relationships and functionality on its own.

From a database concern, a many to many relationship between Table A and Table B is really just a one-to-many relationship between Table A and the pivot table and a one-to-many relationship between Table B and the pivot table.

Therefore, implementing your relationships with a pivot model using hasMany or morphMany is a way for you to accomplish what you're after.